# Attempted to read or write protected memory - .NET EF + Web API

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a relatively simple application that pulls SQL data via a .NET Web API using EF6. There are three tables in the database:

**Product**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProgramID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TechnologyPlatformID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FunctionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProgramManagerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Vendor] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [VendorPOC] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [URL] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] WITH CHECK 
     ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Function] 
     FOREIGN KEY([FunctionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Function] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Function]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] WITH CHECK 
     ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Program] 
     FOREIGN KEY([ProgramID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Program] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Program]
GO
```

Program:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Program]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Program] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Function:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Function]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Function_1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My EDMX looks normal:

[image]

And here's how I'm accessing the data in my repo:

[image]

Suddenly I'm getting the following error when calling `GetProducts()`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I can't seem to figure out what's causing this. Here's what I have tried:

- Made sure "Suppress JIT optimization..." was unchecked in VS
- Repaired .NET Framework on my local machine

Neither worked...however, if I delete the `Function` table in SQL and update my EDMX, the issue is resolved. Why would this table be causing the issue?

Appreciate any input, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning proxy generation off, and see if you still get the same problem.

My initial guess would be that you are including the `Program` directly via `.Include(x => x.Program)`, but `Function` navigation property is being proxied into a lazy property. And when WebAPI tries to serialize it, it throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I disabled proxy generation in the OnContextCreated method, but I'm still getting the error.